# GWT UiBInder property fields

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm design Elements with UiBinder, but I cant find a description of the property fieds an element can have, beside ui:field, ui:style

Does anybody know where it is documented.

PS: the thing I'm currently looking for is how I can speciffy a class from my CSS file.

Since I cant answer it, I'll write it here:

Actuall the thing I was searching for was this site:

Google Web Toolkit API Reference 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?overview-summary.html

To my PS question, setting the style name works with styleName="[CSS-tag-name]" or addSytyleName"[..]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the official documentation for [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)? There it says the following:

> See how the `g:ListBox` element has a `visibleItemCount='1'` attribute? That becomes a call to `ListBox#setVisibleItemCount(int)`. Every one of the widget's methods that follow JavaBean-style conventions for setting a property can be used this way.

@ your PS: If you're working with a `ClientBundle` you can access it with

```
<ui:with field="res" type="path.to.Resources" />
...
<div class="{res.css.myStyle}" />
```